# Creating a DSL Parser for Haystack tags

Tags: c#, parsing

I need to create a C# parser for tags mentioned in https://www.project-haystack.org/tag .

Basically if the user inputs 'Location=Singapore' kind of string, the parser will need to generate the SQL query accordingly. I even tried to google for some tutorials but couldn't find anything useful. Can someone help me to build this parser? As for the reference I am using a source code I found on Github https://github.com/Vanlightly/DslParser. But this doesn't fit 100% to my project. As the user can enter multiple values into their input (Eg: Location=Singapore AND AHU=Type1 AND IBMSPoint=Point7) and etc. So as mentioned above final SQL query needs to be generated accordingly to what user inputs. (Select * From HaystackTags H where (H.TagName='Location' AND H.TagValue='Singapore') AND (H.TagName='AHU' AND H.TagValue='Type1 ') AND (H.TagName='IBMSPoint' AND H.TagValue='Point7')). I have attached how my database looks like, as the final output will be executing the mentioned database table.[Database Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM3wE.png)